# Python, XML, Iterating through tags produces NONE value

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I currently have a program in Python that opens an XML file, iterates through the tags and prints out the contents to a text file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import tkFileDialog

#asks for the location of the file to open
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
#parse in the file
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
#asks for the location/name of court file to save as
file = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
f = open(file, 'w')
f.write("\t\t\tReport: \n\n")

#this prints out all tags and text in the right order 
iter_ = tree.getiterator()
for elem in iter_:
    #print (elem.tag, elem.text)
    f.write("\t")
    f.write(elem.tag)
    f.write(": \t\t")
    f.write(str(elem.text))
    f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

The problem is that some of the tags in the XML file don't have any user input, so when the program iterates through, it places NONE in the space, instead of leaving it blank.

Text File output:

```
Crime Report: 

crime_report:       None
case_number:        090
victim_details:     None
victim_first_name:  j
victim_surname:     j
officer_details:    None
officer_name:       j
officer_ID_number:  j
witness_details:    None    
witness_first_name: j
witness_address:    j
```

Current XML file:

```
<crime_report>
    <case_number caseno="unique identifier associated to the case">090
        <victim_details>
            <victim_first_name>j</victim_first_name>
            <victim_surname>j</victim_surname>
        </victim_details>
        <officer_details>
            <officer_name>j</officer_name>
            <officer_ID_number>j</officer_ID_number>
        </officer_details>
        <witness_details>
            <witness_first_name>j</witness_first_name>
            <witness_address>j</witness_address>
        </witness_details>
    </case_number>
</crime_report>
```

I can't figure out how to iterate through, so that these will just be blank, instead of displaying NONE?

Comment: Coulnd't you just stick a conditional in your output code?  `if elem.text is not None: ...`

Comment: Thank you, i don't know why I didn't think to do that!  I guess I thought it would be more complicated.